# SSMS: Restart the values on a IDENTITY field

Tags: sql-server, identity

I am starting to use SSMS to manage a database and I am having a problem I would appreciate some help with.

I have a table that was created with

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Machine](
        [Machine_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Machine_alias] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Machine_ip] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Machine_stockWarning] [int] NOT NULL,
    .....
CONSTRAINT [PK_machine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Machine_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then I tried to add a row manually and the Machine_id became 1, but there was something wrong with this line so I deleted it. 
Then I tried to add another row, but this time Machine_id is 2. How can I reinitiate the count so that it starts on 1 again?

Comment: `Truncate table dbo.Machine` will also reset the seed value to the original specification

Answer (score 1):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename',reseed,1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose, `GO` after this?

Comment: Thank you it worked. Just a comment, since I wanted the new id to be 1 I had to do the above operation with reseed,0.

Comment: `GO` is a batch separator and [used by client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) application, not SQL Server itself.